# Trying to get a website on my Homestead VM running on Phones locally

Tags: networking, routes, vagrant, ip, xip.io

i have a website i'm developing in **Laravel** running on a **Homestead** VM, and i'd like to be able to see it on **both my and one of my colleague's phones** when i'm trying to design the **responsive** Mobile parts of it.

I'm trying to use **xip.io** to achieve that, what i've done is, i looked at my **private IP address** from my Windows network settings page. (198.169.100.21)

I've defined in my **HOSTS** file that the domain `dev.198.169.100.21.xip.io` should direct to 10.10.21.1 *(ip of my vagrant instance running on my machine)*

Then, i SSH into my Vagrant box and tell **NGINX** to route all requests to `dev.198.169.100.21.xip.io` to my project.

I go to that address on my IPhone, it works, so far so good, i just need to make sure i'm logged into the **company's access point** and i'm good. The problem is that my colleagues can't see the site on their own mobile phones, even though they are using the same access point as me...

Am i missing something here? I hope someone who's used **xip.io** in the past can help me out with this. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You are confused about Private IPv4 addressing because `198.169.100.21` is _not_ a private IPv4 address. Private IPv4 addresses are defined in _[RFC 1918, Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin I followed what is written here

http://www.howtogeek.com/117371/how-to-find-your-computers-private-public-ip-addresses/

If this is incorrect then do you know how i can get my actual private IP address on Windows? Or Mac if you don't know about Windows.
I'd really appreciate it, it worked fine on MY phone, which has a different IP of it's own right? Doesn't make sense... It should've worked on others as long as they were connected to the same network...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for directly answering here as I cannot make a comment based on my reputation.

In my case where I want to access my vagrant machine from any other device aside from my host machine (connected in the same access point), I do a BRIDGED connection by adding another adapter in the `Vagrantfile`, instead of using only a NAT and host-only adapters. But I guess you may have tried or not like that idea?

I have no idea how xip.io works, but checking its website is it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed  the problem, the issue was dumb, i forgot to add port **8000** on my mobile phones, **Homestead** uses port 8000 by default so you need to add it as well.

```
dev.198.169.100.21.xip.io:8000
```